# Kafka streams: Multiple stream applications for multiple topic partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an input topic with 2 partitions and 2 kafka stream applications with same application.id and different sink topics.

1) I start both applications together and they start receiving data but when I kill one of the applications, the other one keeps getting stuck at this. (FYI,The consumer setting has SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG set to 120000)

> [2017-10-08 00:26:17,297] DEBUG [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | ]Sending Heartbeat request for group test.joins.hourly to coordinator :9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
>   [2017-10-08 00:26:17,398] DEBUG [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test.joins.hourly] Received successful Heartbeat response for group test.joins.hourly (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)

2) How can I make sure that the second application starts processing records from both partitions? How can I prove this?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the other one is stuck"? How long have you waited for it to start consuming?

In your case it might take 2 minutes for cluster to rebalance your consumers after you kill one of them. It also depends on `heartbeat.interval.ms` - the smaller it is, the smaller average time to rebalance will be.

Comment: I get this error `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException: task [0_1] Failed to lock the state directory for task 0_1` and the above sending heartbeat request and received successful heartbeat keeps running on loop for more than 2 minutes.

Comment: The lock should get released eventually. If not, it's a bug. What version do you use? Bug related to logs got fixed over time -- upgrade to latest version might resolve the issue (note, Kafka 1.0 is going to be released soon). If your application is in a bad state now, you might need to delete the state directory manually to get a clean restart.